# How to convert a sparse 2D array in COO to a dense 2D array?

Tags: python, numpy, 2d, sparse-matrix, kernel-density

I need to write a Python function sparse2dense(indices, values) that converts
a sparse 2D array in coordinate list format (COO) to a dense 2D array.

here is the indices and the values:

indices = [[0,1], [0,2], [1, 3], [2, 1]]
values = [6,1, 5, 3]

Comment: Are you already using the `scipy.sparse` module?  That has a `to_array` method.  Or you could create a `zeros` array of the right shape, and do `arr[indices[:,0], indices[:,1]] = values`.  Have you spent much time reading the basic `numpy` documentation, especially the stuff about indexing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Numpy array from sparse representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70683821/create-numpy-array-from-sparse-representation)